# Get all referenced assemblies from a given assembly (using Roslyn or via reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn, solution, csproj

I am using Roslyn to do some code analysis on a solution and some of the projects within the solution have references to 3rd party assemblies.

Is there any way to retrieve the list of referenced assemblies, either via Roslyn or via reflection?

E.g. I have Solution = {ProjA, ProjB, ProjC} and ProjC references 3rd party assemblies = {3rdX, 3rdY} => I want to get 3rdX and 3rdY assemblies.

3rdX, 3rdY assemblies are not part of the solution: they can be Nuget loaded 3rd party assemblies for instance.

Comment: If you have access to the Assembly object (for assembly A lets call it) there is a method on it called GetReferencedAssemblies that will return an array containing all the assemblies that assembly A references. That might be of help to you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetReferencedAssemblies

Comment: sorry just to be clear it returns an array of AssemblyName objects not an array of Assembly objects

Comment: But if are running the application, you should be able to [load the assembly from the name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netframework-4.7#System_Reflection_Assembly_Load_System_Reflection_AssemblyName_). You may run into problems when you're doing this as an external tool and assembly resolution may behave differently when you just have the reference.

Comment: In the roslyn if you have a [Project](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,d40daa52fa32a6c4,references) object that represents your ProjC you can retrieve all [referenced projects](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,aca2aeb9e2ea5011,references) or all [referenced metadata](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,470493c41fa57bab,references)

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Project object only provides the referenced projects in the solution, not 3rd party NET assemblies =>which is what I need.

Comment: @MartinUllrich your comment and Dave's are correct. Please post an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @TamasIonut, as I pointed out [MetadataReferences](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,470493c41fa57bab,references) provided all metadata (assemblies) that don't include to current solution, like assemblies from nuget and so on.